# Add column during loop with specific value

Tags: python, pandas

Imagine that I have the following dict:

```
 configs = {
    'CONFIG1': [
        {
            "server": "SERVER_1",
            "description": "Testing server 1.",
        },
        {
            "server": "SERVER_2",
            "description": "Testing server 2.",
        }
    ],
    'CONFIG2': [
        {
            "server": "SERVER_3",
            "description": "Testing server 3.",
        },
        {
            "server": "SERVER_4",
            "description": "Testing server 4.",
        }
    ],
    'CONFIG3': [
        
    ]
}
```

I want to organize this config into a dataframe so that it is like this:

| server | description | config_name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| SERVER_1 | Testing server 1. | CONFIG1 |
| SERVER_2 | Testing server 2. | CONFIG1 |
| SERVER_3 | Testing server 3. | CONFIG2 |
| SERVER_4 | Testing server 4. | CONFIG2 |

I also want to prevent empty configuration keys such as CONFIG3 from being added to the dataframe.

I've tried doing it like this:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame()

for config in configs:
    if configs[config]:
        df = df.append(configs[config], ignore_index=True)
        df['config_name'] = config
    

print(df)
```

But the configuration name is not right. The output is:

| server | description | config_name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| SERVER_1 | Testing server 1. | CONFIG2 |
| SERVER_2 | Testing server 2. | CONFIG2 |
| SERVER_3 | Testing server 3. | CONFIG2 |
| SERVER_4 | Testing server 4. | CONFIG2 |

Comment: Every time you do `df['config_name'] = config` you are setting the value for the entire column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us try `explode`

```
out = pd.Series(configs).explode().dropna().apply(pd.Series)
Out[17]: 
           server        description
CONFIG1  SERVER_1  Testing server 1.
CONFIG1  SERVER_2  Testing server 2.
CONFIG2  SERVER_3  Testing server 3.
CONFIG2  SERVER_4  Testing server 4.
```

Answer (score 2):

Do not repeatedly append to a dataframe. `concat` is almost always a better choice:

```
pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(d).assign(config_name=k) 
           for k,d in configs.items()
          ])
```

Output:

```
     server        description config_name
0  SERVER_1  Testing server 1.     CONFIG1
1  SERVER_2  Testing server 2.     CONFIG1
0  SERVER_3  Testing server 3.     CONFIG2
1  SERVER_4  Testing server 4.     CONFIG2
```

Answer (score 0):

`df['config_name'] = config` assigns this to all rows in the df, not just the rows you just added.

Add it as an entry in the dictionaries before appending to the df.

```
for name, dicts in configs.items():
    if dicts:
        for d in dicts:
            d['config_name'] = name
        df = df.append(dicts, ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: This will be slow for large data. @Barmar You could append to a list instead

Comment: Not significantly slower than the original code. This just fixes the bug, it's not the optimal way to do it.

Comment: Yes. I agree with that.

Answer (score 0):

A one-liner would be using list comprehension

```
df = pd.DataFrame([{**d, 'config_name': k} for k,v in configs.items() for d in v])
```

**Output**

```
     server        description config_name
0  SERVER_1  Testing server 1.     CONFIG1
1  SERVER_2  Testing server 2.     CONFIG1
2  SERVER_3  Testing server 3.     CONFIG2
3  SERVER_4  Testing server 4.     CONFIG2
```